# Android MainActivity perform child activity actions after backpress

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-recyclerview

I have a problem with my MainActivity and his Child Activity, Both of my activity (Lets call them **Activity Main** and **Activity Child**) have as main layout component a **RecyclerView**.
The Main activity's recyclerView has 2 elements (Main.1 and Main.2), The Child's recycler has 4 elements (Child.1, Child.2, etc).

**My problem is**:
If i'm in the child activity and i perform fast: {Press Back button --> Touch on Main.2 element (for example)}

My application will **perform** the **action of the element of the child activity** that was in that position even if main activity layout is already on screen

Which could be the problem?
Thank you in advance

Comment: If the child activity isn't completely gone yet then it could still be possible to use it. You would know if back longer wait then touch works with activity main. IF you expect users to actually do this and you feel its a problem, then you can just detect back press and then block everything from the child activity temporarily until its gone.

Comment: @CmosBattery thank you for your answer, i think your idea could be a solution, i thought that was my fault

Comment: Android has moments where things can still be around waiting to be removed. Like I said though if you wait longer and the parent activity works (the child activity no longer triggered) then it seems to be one of those times. Android should be at fault unless you did something like make things invisible, etc but where they can still be used. But if the child Activity is finished then it cannot be used until another one is started. It takes time for stuff to change so I'm running with its not your fault.